# How to send mails for specific domains at different smarthost on Edge server

Tags: exchange

I have Exchange2019 (MBX) and Exchange2019 (EdgeTransport). EdgeSubscription is in place and send connector which was automatically created during subscription "EdgeSync-OrgName to Internet" is configured to send email through smarthost. Now I want to send emails to some specific domains through different smarthost so I have created new send connector and in address space put these domains and choose as source server EdgeTransport server. When I sent test email I could see that EdgeTransport server trying to send email through "general" smarthost (* as a address space) not through smarthost defined for specific domain.
What is wrong?
Thanks in advance
Juraj

Comment: Just one additional info, when I switched source server in send connector to MBX server email started to send through smarthost specified for given domains. But of course it is not expected behavior as I want email to be sent via EdgeTransport server. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, when messages are sent to external recipients, they go through a connector selection process, exchange must select the best connector to route the message through. The decisions that are required to select this connector are described in the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/mail-routing/connector-selection?view=exchserver-2019#selecting-the-connector-for-an-external-recipient) for your reference.